# Gnuplot: how to (systematically) multiply each column by a factor

Tags: gnuplot

I have some data that look like this:

```
# time  Ux      Uy      sigXX   sigYY   sigXY
1.e-3   0.001  -0.001   1.e6    0.7e6   2.e5
2.e-3   0.002  -0.0025  2.e6    1.2e6   5.e5
3.e-3   0.004  -0.0035  2.8e6   1.4e6   9.e5
```

as you can guess the data is in SI units (s, m, Pa), and I'm using gnuplot.

For readability in my plots, I'd like to put the x/ytics in (ms, mm, MPa). This is classically done with `using ($..)`:

```
set ylabel 'sig[MPa]'
plot 'data.dat' using ($1*1000):($4*1.e-6)
```

... but adding all those parentheses is getting tedious (as I `replot` a lot this file). I'm dreaming of something like:

```
set datafactor $1 1000
set datafactor $4 1.e-6
plot 'data.dat' u 1:4
```

but couldn't find it yet.
I know I could also use redirection and an external script to do the conversion on the fly (I'll post it as an answer if someone's interested), but it seems too complex for such a simple and common task.

Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a native gnuplot way to do this kind of conversion once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have 3 options:

1. change your datafile permanently with whatever software
2. multiply the datafile columns once when you load them to gnuplot
3. multiply the columns everytime when you plot them

Option 1 you probably don't want, option 3 you definitely don't want, so, maybe option 2 might be a solution which would be similar to your Python code. You basically load your file into a datablock, scale it and then plot this datablock.

```
### mulitply data columns with factor
reset session

set table $Data
    plot 'data.dat' u ($1*1000):($2*1000):($3*1000):($4*1e-6):($5*1e-6):($6*1e-6) w table
unset table

plot $Data u 1:4
### end of code
```

**Limitations:**

Keep in mind, in case you have some comment lines or data separated by single or multiple emtpy lines which in some cases might be essential for plotting, these lines will be all removed when `plot ... with table`. If you need these empty lines there might be more complicated gnuplot workarounds or you need to call external software.

Comment: That is exactly the thing I was looking for. Thanks for pointing out these two concepts : 'inline data' and 'table'.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the (not simple) solution with an external script.
In gnuplot:

```
data='< ./scale.py data.dat 1000 1000 1000 1.e-6 1.e-6 1.e-6'
plot data u 1:4
```

where scale.py is the following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import numpy as np

fic = sys.argv[1]
data = np.loadtxt(fic)
factors = map(float, sys.argv[2:])
print ('# scale', fic, 'by', list(factors))

for i,f in enumerate(factors):
    data[:,i] *= f

np.savetxt(sys.stdout, data)
```

This would suit me if the conversion function was some complex operation. But here my question seems so simple that I guess a gnuplot native solution should exist.